# Disable rake task's console output in Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, minitest

I've got a rake task which provides some output to the console. This output is useful in tracking the progress of execution and is achieved with `puts` like so:

```
task :clean => :environment do
  # Some code
  puts 'Doing work'
end
```

I've got a test for that task written in `Minitest` and it provides the same console output like if was called manually. This messes up the 'green dots' screen when I'm running the whole test suite for the project.

Is there an option to disable the console output (effect of the `puts` statement) in the test environment? Optionally, is there another way of showing the messages when the task is run manually that can be hidden in the test environment.

I have explored an option of replacing `puts` with `Rails.logger.info`. This could be configured per environment, but it prints the output to the log and not in the terminal window where the task is run.

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily redirect `STDOUT` to `/dev/null` and reinstate it afterwards.

```
original_stdout = $stdout
$stdout = File.open(File::NULL, 'w')

# ... do your tests ...

$stdout = original_stdout
```

Another approach would be to put the code that's currently directly in your Rake task into an object of some description, and use dependency injection with a default value. For example:

```
# your rake file
task :clean => :environment do
  MyTaskObject.new.call
end

# my_task_object.rb
class MyTaskObject
  attr_reader :io

  def initialize(io = $stdout)
    @io = io
  end

  def call
    # ...actions
    io.puts "output"
    # more actions...
  end
end
```

Then rather than running the rake task directly in your tests, you can test the object, and pass in your own I/O object to take the place of the stdout:

```
test '...' do
  io = StringIO.new

  MyTaskObject.new(io).call

  # assert here as usual
end
```

One advantage with this approach is that using StringIO will allow you to interrogate `io.string`, so you could also test what is being output if you needed to.